# Как определить координаты ЖД станции по коду ЕСР?

Tags: яндекс-карты, геолокация

У меня есть название станции, имя ЖД дороги и код ЕСР. Нужно отобразить набор станций на карты. Сейчас ищу станции по строке имя ЖД дороги + имя станции, но иногда находится совершенно не то (к примеру станция в Казахстане Коскудук, пытаюсь найти точку на карте Западно-Сибирская жд Коскудук и по итогу мне отображается первая найденная точка - Западно-Сибирская равнина, где-то в болоте).

Казалось бы для этого у нас есть ЕСР код станции, но не нашёл В Я.Api такого входного параметра и поиск открытых справочников в интернете с api НЕ в виде html страницы результатов не дал. У РЖД тоже ничего похожего не нашёл.

Можно, конечно, завести у себя в БД, но может есть уже готовые примеры сервисов или понимание, как по коду ЕСР однозначно находить координаты станции?

Comment: Это не вопрос про API Яндекс Карт. Это поиск подходящей базы ЕСР код станций с доступом через API. Яндекс этой информации в API Карт не держит и вернуть не может.

Comment: В Яндексе есть функционал по поиску промежуточных станций для поездов, которые возвращают в том числе и код ЕСР, но нет функционала поиска станции по этому самому коду?
Окей, для меня это было неочевидно, я предполагал, что просто не могу найти соответствующую документацию

Comment: Промежуточные станции? А это не Яндекс Расписания? Просто к Картам они отношения как такового не имеют.

Comment: Ох как. Да, это Я.Расписание. Понял, тогда  к картам действительно никакого отношения нет